# Azure CLI and loop

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this with Azure CLI, I have about 50 custom domains I'd like to add to an app service. I use Azure CLI to accomplish this:

```
az webapp config hostname add --resource-group MYRESOURCE_GROUP--webapp-name MYAPPSERVICE_NAME --hostname DOMAIN.COM
```

Sure I can go ahead and copy and paste each domain, but I rather do it with a script.

How can I write a script to accomplish this? Right now my the domain list is in a txt file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to write a powershell script. This script will read your txt file and loop thru all your domains:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\mycustomdomains.txt) {
  az webapp config hostname add --resource-group MYRESOURCE_GROUP --webapp-name MYAPPSERVICE_NAME --hostname $line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your shell language to loop over the items in the file.  If you are using bash, you can loop using these instructions: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on a Windows system or just prefer to use bash this should work for you

Copy/paste all the domains in to the script self:

```
# Define an array of domains on a single line ...
DOMAINS=( domain1 domain2 domain3 )
# or define it on multiple lines, use '\' to 
# indicate that the command continues on the next line
DOMAINS=( domain1 \
   domain2 \
   domain3 \
   domain4 \
   domain5 )

for DOMAIN in "${DOMAINS[@]}"
do
  echo "Add $DOMAIN"
  az webapp config hostname add --resource-group MYRESOURCE_GROUP--webapp-name MYAPPSERVICE_NAME --hostname DOMAIN
done
```

Or read the domains directly from the file (assuming that each domain is on a new line):

```
FILE="./domains.txt"

while read DOMAIN
do
  echo "Add $DOMAIN"
  az webapp config hostname add --resource-group MYRESOURCE_GROUP--webapp-name MYAPPSERVICE_NAME --hostname DOMAIN
done < $FILE
```