# Register multiple resource providers with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm using this simple piece of code to register resource providers in Azure.

`az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Sql`

**Situation**: I would need to register 30 or so resource providers for a blank subscription that is receiving resources from another subscription through Azure resource move.

**Question**: Can I provide a list of resource providers (namespaces) to that code and what would be the syntax to do that?

Thanks guys!

Comment: According to the situation, you can use loop with Azure CLI. For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827724/azure-cli-and-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! You could store all of the desired namespaces that you want to register as an array or in a file and loop through it in a Shell or Powershell script.

As an example (in PS):

```
foreach($rp in Get-Content .\rp.txt) {
  az provider register --namespace $rp --subscription $subscription
}
```

Or this (in Shell):

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./rp.txt"
while read rp
do
  echo "$rp"
  az provider register --namespace $rp
done < "$input"
```

Hope this helps.